# Copy an object changing a field of an included object

Tags: scala

I have the following two case classes, note that the second one includes the first one (User case class).

```
case class User(sk: Int,
                userid: String,
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String,
                email: String,
                notes: String)

case class UserApplyRequest(action: String, user: User)
```

Given an object of UserApplyRequest (obj1) I need to copy it to another object (obj2) but changing only the `notes` field.

The following doesn't work:

```
val obj2 = obj1.copy(user.notes = "new value")
```

How to copy a field that is included in an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val obj2 = obj1.copy(user = obj1.user.copy(notes="new value""))
```

the `user` is a nested `case class`, you need to copy also.